# Probability functions are sequences?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Are discrete probability functions just a particular kind of sequence?

This never occurred to me, but then once it did it seemed obvious, however I can't find anything online about it? (Either because it's so obvious, or so obviously wrong??)

For example take the sequence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=1$

Writing in terms of x, we have $p(x) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^x}$ this is a discrete probability function? Because:

1. $p(x) \ge 0 \; \forall x \in \mathbb{N}$
2. $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^x}=1$

**Questions:**

1. Is this a discrete probability function, does it have a name?
2. Are discrete probability functions, just sequences?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure you can see them as sequences. Also you need $\sum p(x) =1$ instead of $\sum xp(x)=1$.

Comment: Oh yeah lol, thanks, I realised I confused $E(X)$ with the definition of a pf, thanks! Do you know if that 'distribution' has a name? (I'm going to edit the question now to correct it)

Comment: This is a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Comment: Every sequence $(a_n)$ with all $a_n \geq 0$ and $\sum_n a_n = 1$ defines a probability distribution, yes.  But discrete probability distributions may have more information than a sequence. For example, a distribution with $P(X=1.5) = .5$ and $P(X = \pi) = .5$. The sequence $(.5, .5)$ wouldn't tell you what values $X$ can take.

Comment: Ah ofc, a discrete distribution doesn't have to be defined over the natural numbers. Just some domain consisting of discrete intervals? (Would that be an appropriate phrasing). Would it also be correct to say then that, not every discrete probability function is a sequence because, sequences are only defined over Natural Numbers? Thanks @JairTaylor

Comment: Also @JairTaylor I'd happily vote/tick your answer as correct if you wanted to copy paste it as an answer. Not that you need the points lol

Comment: OK, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, this is an example of a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

On your second question: Yes, every sequence $(a_n)$ with all $a_n\geq 0$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=1$$ defines a probability distribution on $\mathbb{N}$. But in general a discrete probability distributions may take more data to define it than just the sequence of probabilities. For example, a distribution with $P(X = 1.5) = 1/2$ and $P(X = \pi) = 1/2$. The sequence $(1/2,1/2)$ wouldn't tell you what values $X$ can take. In general, a discrete probability distribution is defined by a finite (or countable) sample space $\Omega$ and a function $\rho: \Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $$\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} \rho(\omega) = 1.$$

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Jair! Btw if you have time, was my previous comment correct? "Ah ofc, a discrete distribution doesn't have to be defined over the natural numbers. Just some domain consisting of discrete intervals? (Would that be an appropriate phrasing). Would it also be correct to say then that, not every discrete probability function is a sequence because, sequences are only defined over Natural Numbers?"

Comment: Yes, except I would say a "domain consisting of finitely many elements" (or just "finite domain") rather than "domain consisting of discrete intervals."

Comment: Okay cool, would that definition contain the idea that the interval between each element was the same? In fact is that even necessary for probability. I.e. could a random variable take only values, 1,2, 2.3, and 70? Thanks, I'm learning so much!

Comment: No it's not necessary, you could can define a random variables taking whatever set of values you like. Cheers!

Comment: You're awesome! All the best